# $f''(x)=12x^2+6ax+3=3(2x+a/2)^2+3(1-a^2/4)$ Where can be this derivative negative? Can it be negative?

Tags: calculus, inequality

$f''(x)=12x^2+6ax+3=3(2x+a/2)^2+3(1-a^2/4)$ I still don't how to calculate for which a parameter can this expression be negative.

Comment: A quadratic function $bx^{2}+cx+d$ is negative only between its roots if $b>0$ and positive only between its roots if $b<0$. You have to compute the roots and so you'll be able to say where your $f''$ will be negative (between these roots). The expression will depends on $a$.

Comment: yeah but I'm still far away from the solution.

Comment: The roots are given by $\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{4}$ if I'm not mistaken. If $|a|\le 2$, the function $f''$ will always be positive. If $|a|>2$, then it will be negative between the roots.

Comment: I still don't see exactly how did you calculate but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comments were maybe too short, I answer you properly.

If you have a quadratic function $g(x)=bx^{2}+cx+d$, it is a well-known fact that $g$ will be of the sign of $b$ anywhere but between its roots, where it will have the sign of $-b$. For example, if you take $x^{2}-1$, it is zero or negative only when $x\in[-1,1]$.

The roots of $g$ are given by $$\frac{-c\pm\sqrt{c^{2}-4bd}}{2b}$$

1) If $c^{2}<4bd$, there is **no real root**, so that the function $g$ will have strictly the sign of $b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For example, $g(x)=-x^{2}-1$

2) If there is a **root of multiplicity** $2$, i.e. if $c^{2}=4bd$, there will be only one root $\frac{-c}{2b}$, so that the function will have the sign of $b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and of course $g(-c/2b)=0$.

3) If there are **two real roots**, the function will have the same sign as $b$ only out of the interval $$\left[\frac{-c-\sqrt{c^{2}-4bd}}{2b}\,,\,\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^{2}-4bd}}{2b}\right]$$
(note that it is possible that $\frac{-c-\sqrt{c^{2}-4bd}}{2b}>\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^{2}-4bd}}{2b}$ if $b<0$ but it is a detail).

**Back to your particular question**, $b=12>0$, $c=6a$, $d=3$. The roots are then

$$\frac{-6a\pm\sqrt{36a^{2}-4\cdot36}}{24}=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{4}$$

The roots are not real if $a^{2}<4\Leftrightarrow |a|<2$, so that the function $f''$ will always be positive (since $b=12>0$). The root is of multiplicity $2$ if $\sqrt{a^{2}-4}=0$, i.e. $a=\pm 2$. Again, $f''$ will always we positive.

The roots are real if $a^{2}-4>0$, i.e. $|a|>2$. Then, your function will be positive everywhere but on the following interval:

$$\left[\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{4}\,,\,\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{4}\right]$$

Comment: You're welcome! Happy if it is clear for you.

Comment: yeah, I understand it finally many thanks to you:)

Comment: No problem, that's the purpose!